# Make website span to user?

Tags: html, css, web

How would I make a website adopt the dimensions of a user's device who is browsing it, in order to avoid problems that would deter from aesthetics like scrolling the width of the page in order to see full content.

If that is not possible what are the best dimensions?

Comment: Please research "responsive web design". This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Take the [tour], read the [help/dont-ask], learn [ask]...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of techniques you can use, most of which are summarized under the term "responsive design". Your first commentor is correct when they say you should research this topic, as it's too broad to answer, but let me make the base effort of giving anyone looking a few pointers (as far as techniques go, not in the form of hyperlinks)

### Percentage Values

First of all, what always has worked - use proportional widths in your CSS, like so:

```
#content { max-width: 800px; width: 100%; } /* this spans around #left and #right */
#left { width: 25%; }
#right { width: 75%; }
#right img { max-width: 100%; }
```

Using these values is often not the best way of putting pre-made layouts into place, but are the essentials of responsive web design that people sometimes disregard. However while you will be able to contain all content to the screen in most scenarios, you won't be able to optimize output for certain screen dimensions - and that's where media queries come in.

### Media Queries

Media queries are a part of the CSS3 specification, and meant to apply styles only to a certain device, screen size or other output conditions. It's the tool of choice to draw elements in different ways for different devices or resolutions.

Most of all, you'll see a declaration such as this:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Everything between the parentheses will only be shown if the user's screen is at least 600px wide (at the currently used orientation).

There are other types of selectors, letting you filter for device types (such as screen, or tv) or orientation (landscape or portrait). Be advised that those aren't always faithfully implemented on all devices for reasons too broad to mention here.

[more about media queries on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

### The Viewport Metatag

As part of your `<head>` content, you can add a metatag named viewport, in which you can set certain outlines for the device to render your webpage. As some mobile devices in particular will scale your content to fit the screen instead of using the real screen resolution, the viewport tag allows you to fine-tune how your page should be rendered.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

In this case, the following things are being set:

- the rendering width of the webpage should be the screen resolution of the device
- the webpage should be initially rendered at 100%
- the maximum zoom level is 100% (preventing the user from zooming in)
- the user is not allowed to scale the page at all (preventing the user from zooming at all)

[more about the viewport metatag on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

### Techniques

When working with media queries for a while, web designers have agreed that mobile-first design is the best practice to work from. This means (very roughly outlined) that by default, you CSS will apply to the smallest resolution, and from there you'll add more definitions by using `min-width` media queries. This ensures that even on the oldest, least maintained browser on the universe, your webpage will render readable (if not optimized and pretty), and while creating it, you will have an easier time than going the other way 'round.

The technical side isn't everything, though: Mobile-first design makes you aware of the content of your webpage - the actual part your viewers are interested in. You now are forced to find a meaningful place for every element on your page, whereas otherwise, you'd probably put elements you don't necessarily need in there, just to `display:none` them for lower resolutions, indicating they weren't all that important from the start.

[more on mobile first from Metamonks](http://metamonks.com/mobile-first-vs-responsive/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike that this is very vague, you will want to look up some tutorials about responsive design.

Nevertheless, you might want to use a view port meta tag such as this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Check out this thorough documentation about using the viewport meta tag to control the layout for different device screen sizes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag